# How do I correct an error code 0 in MQL4 OrderModify() call?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, mql4

I have this code below which I am using to test trailing stop function. It works on some currency pairs and doesn't work in others. It's returning error code 0 (zero). I will be grateful if somebody can help me out

```
void modifyTrade() {
  TrailingStop = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL);
   if(TrailingStop>0)
     {
     for(int z = 0; z<OrdersTotal(); z++)
     {
      OrderSelect(z,SELECT_BY_POS);
      if(Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>Point*TrailingStop)
        {
         if(OrderStopLoss()<Bid-Point*TrailingStop)
           {
            bool res=OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(Bid-Point*TrailingStop,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,Blue);
            if(!res) {
               Print("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",GetLastError());
               //if(Symbol()=="EURNZD")
              Alert("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",GetLastError()," ; ",OrderSymbol());
               }
            else {
               Print("Order modified successfully.");
               }
           }
        }
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

1. once called, `GetLastError()` is reset. If you are both printing and alerting the last error, you should store the error code prior to printing/alerting.
2. you should check `OrderSelect()` succeeds.
3. you should iterate over orders in the opposite direction to ensure your code carried on operating should an order be closed mid-check.
4. You require different code for longs and shorts
5. Your code is prone to errors simply because you have no buffer and are trying to trail price at the minimum stop level. By the time your order modification is received by the trading server it is highly likely price may have moved back inside the stop level area resulting in a modification error.

```
void modifyTrade()
{
   TrailingStop = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL);
   if(TrailingStop>0)
   {
      for(int z=OrdersTotal()-1; z>=0; z--)
      {
         if(OrderSelect(z,SELECT_BY_POS))
         {
            if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
            {
               if(Bid-OrderStopLoss()>TrailingStop*point)
               {
                  bool res=OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(Bid-Point*TrailingStop,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,Blue);
                  if(!res)
                  {
                     int err=GetLastError();
                     Print("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",err);
                     Alert("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",err);
                  }
                  else Print("Order modified successfully.");
               }
            }
            if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
            {
               if(OrderStopLoss()-Ask>TrailingStop*point)
               {
                  bool res=OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(Ask+Point*TrailingStop,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0,Blue);
                  if(!res)
                  {
                     int err=GetLastError();
                     Print("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",err);
                     Alert("Error in OrderModify. Error code=",err);
                  }
                  else Print("Order modified successfully.");
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, type-casting int into string is an artificial move, the _LastError system variable can be efficiently re-used ( i.e. it keeps its value, sure unless print()-fun does not fail by itself :o) ) & the print()-function is by-design poly-morphic and can print int after string after any other type - no offense here.

Comment: No offence @user3666197, but I think you need to read the documentation before attempting to correct another users answer. In MQL4, the [GetLastError()](https://docs.mql4.com/check/getlasterror) contents are reset once called. Whilst the Print function doesn't require a string, it's just my normal practice and acceptable to type-cast the error to a string. If it caused problems (which it wouldn't), it is simple to change to `IntegerToString(GetLastError())` or use int. There are far more pressing errors in the answer you have provided which I have attempted to correct/clarify?

Comment: You might recognise my comment has NOT mentioned the function, but rather the system built-in variable, that is not reset on re-use. 2nd fact: MQL4 print()-function IS polymorphic, such that placing the int-parameter (be it delivered from _LastError or not) does NOT require any type-cast. Last, but not least, declaration of int was repaired (from string) and WAS fully compliant with the documented return value (being int, never a string). Having used MQL4 since 200x, i.e. almost for ages :o) and having survived with code-base even the "new"-MQL4 changes, gives me some sense of what & how works

Comment: Let me propose to focus on some more useful work, than raising objections against documented MQL4 language properties. All the best to you, stay well & positive, life is so more interesting, than any artificial flame-throwing.

Comment: @user3666197 I'm not sure why you raised such an inconsequential point when as you say "focus on more useful work". The users question and code specifically used the `GetLastError()` function. My code simply educated the user that using this function call resets the last error and shows how to use it properly. The are far bigger problems with the code.

Comment: Sure, there are ... RefreshRates() missing being the next one and we may follow on & on & on. Forgive me not to do so. All the best --( Over & Out )--

Comment: I totally agree, like iterating orders in the wrong direction. All the best --( Over & Out )--

Answer (score 0):

Error being

> `0 == ERR_NO_ERROR ... No error returned`

is rather ok, no need to "correct" it, it means there was nothing to actually improve.

There are a few risky points to mention - prices move, `STOPLEVEL` parameter can either ( be careful on this - a hostile case if appears in live-trading ) and also be informed, that there are other levels, that may prohibit an `OrderModify()`-call from being Broker-T&C-compliant (and will get rejected for that reason)

Somehow improved code may work in this sense :

```
void modifyTrade()
{
     TrailingStop = MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL );
     if ( TrailingStop >  0 )
     {
        for (  int z = 0; z <  OrdersTotal(); z++ )
        {
            if !OrderSelect( z, SELECT_BY_POS ) continue;
        // ______________________________________________________ CRITICAL
            RefreshRates();
        // ______________________________________________________ Bid + Ask valid...
            if ( TrailingStop != MarketInfo( OrderSymbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL ) )
            { // TrailingStop CHANGED ... LOG, renegotiate such Broker policy 
                 TrailingStop  = MarketInfo( OrderSymbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL
                 }
        // ______________________________________________________ STOPLEVEL valid...
            if (  Bid - OrderOpenPrice() >  Point * TrailingStop
               && OrderType() == OP_BUY )
            {
                if (  OrderStopLoss() <  Bid - Point * TrailingStop )
                {
                   bool res = OrderModify( OrderTicket(),
                                           OrderOpenPrice(),
                                           NormalizeDouble( Bid - Point * TrailingStop, Digits ),
                                           OrderTakeProfit(),
                                           0,
                                           Blue
                                           );
                   if ( !res )
                   {
                       Print( "Error in OrderModify. Error code=", _LastError );
                    // if (  Symbol() == "EURNZD" )
                       Alert( "Error in OrderModify. Error code=", _LastError, " ; ", OrderSymbol() );
                       }
                   else
                   {
                      Print( "Order modified successfully." );
                      }
                   }
                }
            if (  OrderOpenPrice() - Ask >  Point * TrailingStop
               && OrderType() == OP_SELL )
            {
                ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```